# Foreign key constraint fail with JPA (ManyToOne relationship)

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys, many-to-one

I have 2 tables

```
@Entity
public class Glass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
     private Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Beer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "FK_GLASS", referencedColumnName = "ID" )
    private Glass glass;
    ...
}
```

For each of my beers, I want to know which glass was used to serve it. If I delete one glass related to a beer, I want to keep the beer in question and set its foreign key to null. Is there a way to do this only with annotations, or do I have to implement a custom method to set the foreign key to null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationship maintenance is the responsibility of the application.

If entity to be removed (`Glass`) is the target of the foreign key (`FK_GLASS`) in the owning table (`Beer`), then the foreign key must be cleared for the remove operation to succeed otherwise it will end up throwing ConstraintViolationException.

So you would need to implement a custom method, i.e.

```
public void removeGlass(long beerId) {
    Beer beer = em.find(Beer.class, beerId)
    if (beer != null) {
        Glass glass = beer.getGlass();
        beer.setGlass(null); // UPDATE BEER SET FK_GLASS=NULL WHERE ID=?
        em.remove(glass);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I thought it was possible to do it with persistence. I tried to keep a list of each beers involved in the relationship, set glass to null for those beers, update it and delete glass but I got the same error. I assume it is not possible that way.